# How to invoke python script from google sheets?

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have google sheets that have multiple tabs that are configured as inputs. I want to have a submit button on google sheets that then triggers a python script. The python script runs right now in Jupyter notebook and loads inputs from google sheets and writes data back to google sheets.

However, I want to start the invocation of the pipeline by using google sheets as UI. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: You can deploy your code as cloud function then call your function with url fetch using: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-http-functions#http-example-python